# PHP - BLOB image rotation when uploading from phone

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob, exif

**Disclaimer: I understand that storing images in a directory vs. database is the better way to go, but please humour me for the sake of learning. Thank you in advance for your help.**

I'm having an issue rotating the image when uploading it into my database as a BLOB and displaying it when a user logs in.

I have tested multiple methods of upload and found the following:

**The image is rotated when:** 
1) Choosing file, then clicking "Take Photo" from a mobile device.

[image: Rotated Image]

**The image is NOT rotated when:** 
1) Choosing file, then clicking "From Gallery" from a mobile device. 
2) A screenshot of the image is taken and uploaded using a desktop computer. 
3) The image is imported using an application such as iPhoto and then uploaded.

[image: Not Rotated Image]

**upload.php** - Upload image to database.

```
<?php

require_once "../config/config.php";
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
  header("Location: ../login/login.html");
} else {
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
}

include "fetchavatar.php";

if(!empty($_FILES['avatar']['name']) && (isset($_POST['upload']))) {
  $name = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
  $temp = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
  $size = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
  $type = $_FILES['avatar']['type'];

  $fp = fopen($temp, 'r');
  $img = fread($fp, filesize($temp));
  fclose($fp);

  if($fetchedrows) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE avatars SET name = ?, type = ?, size = ?, data = ? WHERE user_id = ?;");
  } else {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT into avatars (name, type, size, data, user_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
  }

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $type);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $img);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $id);
    $stmt->execute();

}

header("Location: profile.php");

?>
```

**fetchavatar.php** - Select image from database, store HTML + image into $avatar.

```
<?php

require_once "../config/config.php";
session_start();

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM avatars WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$fetchedrows = $stmt->rowCount();

$_SESSION['avatar'] = base64_encode($result['data']);
$avatar = "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,". $_SESSION['avatar']. "' width='100' height='100'>";

?>
```

**profile.php** - Profile page.

```
<?php

session_start();
include "fetchavatar.php";

?>

<html>
<body>
 <div id="profile_div">
 <h1>Profile Page</h1>

  <?php echo $avatar ?>

  ...

</body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of my latest attempt at rotating the image. When attempting this method, the BLOB data uploaded is blank and the image is no longer displayed. I have tried multiple solutions offered here but have not been successful in either implementing the code correctly or knowing if I'm on the right track.

**upload.php**

```
<?php

...

include "fetchavatar.php";

if(!empty($_FILES['avatar']['name']) && (isset($_POST['upload']))) {
  $name = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
  $temp = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
  $size = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
  $type = $_FILES['avatar']['type'];


  $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($temp));
  $exif = exif_read_data($temp);
  if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
     }
  }

  $fp = fopen($image, 'r');
  $img = fread($fp, filesize($image));
  fclose($fp);

  if($fetchedrows) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE avatars SET name = ?, type = ?, size = ?, data = ? WHERE user_id = ?;");
  } else {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT into avatars (name, type, size, data, user_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
  }

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $type);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $img);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $id);
    $stmt->execute();

}

header("Location: profile.php");

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `$exif` data to see what you're actually getting?

Comment: Do you mean doing a `print_r()` or `var_dump()`? I did that and the orientation for the rotated photos usually have a value of 6. Using the `switch/case` conditional, `case 6` should rotate the image -90 degrees but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your last `upload.php` example it looks like you are attempting to `fopen()` an image resource instead of an image file on the file system.  Try changing the

```
$fp = fopen($image, 'r');
$img = fread($fp, filesize($image));
fclose($fp);
```

to

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image);
$img = addslashes(ob_get_clean());
```

This will write your image resource to a string that can be inserted into the database.

This is also easily modified to output to the file system instead of a database, should you ever change your application.

Comment: I tried replacing the code but it still didn't work. I tried it using your code with my original working upload.php and it inserted blank data for the image.

Comment: That's the issue that stuck out at me.  It may an issue that requires a fair bit of debugging, something that the Stackoverflow format is not well suited to do.  I would recommend taking this to the forums.